# Antisymmetric relation - answer key is wrong

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

If I define a relation $\rho$ on $\Bbb Z$ by:  $x\rho y$ if and only if $x$ is a multiple of $y$. The solution key tells me that this is not an antisymmetric relation.

But say $x$ is a multiple of $y$, then $x=yn$ for some $n\in \Bbb Z$. Then if $y$ is a multiple of $x$, we have $y=xk$ for some $k\in \Bbb Z$.

Hence $x=yn=xnk\implies nk=1$ and hence $x=y$. Which makes this antisymmetric? Is the answer key wrong?

Comment: You can't conclude $nk=1$ if $x=0$.

Comment: @Randall Regardless, if $x=0$ then we conclude $y=0$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't conclude $x=y$ from $nk=1$.

And here is a simple counterexample to it being antisymmetric:

Take $x=1$ and $y=-1$

Comment: Right. Of course. I was thinking about $\Bbb N$ by mistake.

$x=nkx\implies x=0$ or $1=nk \implies n=k=1$ or $n=k=-1$, the latter case yielding $x=-y$.